# Calculate Combination based on position

Tags: algorithm, function, combinations

### I'm having trouble solving this problem:

Create a function that given a character set C, can generate the Nth combination OR return the series of combination given a starting position (Ns) and ending position (Ne) and the maximum length of the combination (Mx).

**A concrete example:**

Let C = [A,B,C]

We know that different combinations would look like the following assuming **Mx = 3** *(the combination would be different for different lengths)*:

```
1. AAA
2. AAB
3. AAC
4. ABA
5. ABB
6. ABC
N. ... Etc
```

If we was to pass the following parameters :

C = [A,B,C] Mx = 3 Ns = 3 Ne = 3

we would expect the following result:

```
AAC
```

If we was to pass the following parameters :

C = [A,B,C] Mx = 3 Ns = 4 Ne = 6

we would expect the following result:

```
4. ABA
5. ABB
6. ABC
```

For the solution, the programming language is not relevant. However C# would be preferred. Also most important would be an explanation of how its solved.

I look forward to the amazing Guru's of Stack Overflow...

Comment: No, its a very small part of a much bigger personal project.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an index **N** (0-based) into the sequence of combinations of **n** symbols, you can get the **i**'th symbol by calculating **N** / **n**<sup>**i**</sup> % **n** (using integer division and remainder)

For example:

```
C = {A, B, C} (giving n = 3)
N = 6
i = 0 => 6 / 3^0 % 3 = 0 (symbol 0 = A)
i = 1 => 6 / 3^1 % 3 = 2 (symbol 2 = C)
i = 2 => 6 / 3^2 % 3 = 0 (symbol 0 = A)
Resulting sequence: ACA
```

The sequence is treated as a base-**n** number, and the individual digits are calculated.

Comment: Excellent, this is *beautifully* simple. this is exactly what I was looking for! I'm marking this this as solved.