# How to get an array of randomly ordered numbers from 1 to N?

Tags: random, duplicates, fortran

The code below generates an array of `N` integer random numbers and stores the result in `random_int_array`

```
 N=20
 allocate(array(N/2))
 call random_seed
 call random_number(array)
 random_int_array=int(array*N)
```

The problem is that I might generates duplicates in `random_int_array` and I don't want that. How can I remove the duplicate from this array or, equivalently, how can I generate a set of unique random numbers?

Note that `array` has a dimension N/2. So the problem is basically extract N/2 numbers, without duplicates, out of N.

Comment: And the simplest possible approach, where you simply skip duplicates, isn't good enough? (move items from random_int_array1 to random_int_array2 if they aren't already in the second array)

Comment: it would be enough but I need a smart way to find the duplicates and get rid of them.

Comment: Never mind, I found this page really useful for my problem: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Remove_duplicate_elements#Fortran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the integers from 1 to 19 in random order.   This would be a shuffle of those integers.   See, e.g., http://tekpool.wordpress.com/2006/10/06/shuffling-shuffle-a-deck-of-cards-knuth-shuffle/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I edited the post it should be clearer now.

Comment: But you could shuffle the N numbers and take only half of them into your array.

Comment: Or just run the shuffle half way.

Comment: The Wikapedia article states that the Fisher-Yates algorithm is suitable when only a portion of the permutation is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to generate one of the possible combinations of size 10 from a set of size 20 ?  There are 184756 such combinations.  You could generate a single random integer in the range [1..184756] and use that as input to a function to create the n-th combination.

This latter problem is regularly raised on SO, for example [Calculate Combination based on position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052688/calculate-combination-based-on-position) contains a solution.

I make no claims that this approach is better in any general way than repeatedly generating random numbers in the right range and throwing away duplicates until you have a set that satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function outside your main program

```
function random_uniform(m)
  implicit none
  integer*8 m
  real*8 random_uniform
  m = mod(7**5*m, 2147483647)
  random_uniform = m / 2147483647.     
end function
```

Then inside the main function, use this function to generate random array:

```
m = 1067 !This is your seed which you can change to get different sequence
do i = 1,20
   array(i) = random_uniform(m)
enddo
```

Note that all the integers are of double precision type (*8). This is must for this function to work properly. Also, to avoid integer division to get random_uniform, we have converted denominator into real (from integer*8)

Comment: Can you describe what it does? How does it guarantee non-repeating values? Is it better than `random_number`? Note the OP wanted random *integer* array.

Comment: Indeed, @VladimirF.  Whilst `m` will be (generally) long-period this doesn't answer the question without a careful description of how `random_uniform` is mapped to the integers.

Comment: As you must have noted, this is a linear congruential generator. It was proposed by Lewis, Goodman and Miller in 1969 and has passed many tests successfully (though better generators are available). Note that period of this generator is 2147483647 which is great for any practical purpose. Getting integer array instead of real numbered array is child's play once we have this function.