# How to randomly reorder N particles?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a configuration of `N` particles and in a loop I want to choose each of them but without `repeat`.  I have `below codes` but I just found out some repeats on it.

```
    do k=1,num
       u=mod(16807.d0*u,2147483647.d0)
       v=u/2147883648.d0
       s=int(dble(num)*v)+1
       if (s.gt.num) s=1
    end do
```

Comment: There many, start with `random_number`, then you can try http://www.astro.multivax.de:8000/helbig/fortran/ranlux.html

Comment: What kind of website is? it can not be opened!

Comment: I don't find the question clear.  If you want to choose each particle from the set without repetition, just go through non-randomly.  Or, do you mean: you want to select each but in a random order; you want a randomly selected subset?

Comment: I guess it's clear that I want to choose particle randomly, because the order way is really easy.
e.g I have `N=8` particle so I want choose one of them randomly and then compute the potential of it based on other 7 particles.

Comment: The unclear part is that, if you want to select just one (not "each"), then what does the "without repeat" mean?  And the code doesn't suggest selecting one.  So, you do want to select all, but in a random order?

Comment: Is your question the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840808/how-to-get-an-array-of-random-number-in-fortran ?

Comment: Sorry sir I guess you did not pay attention, I wrote "I want to choose each of them".

Comment: If I understand you, that is what the previous question does.  It describes how to select each item randomly precisely one time.  In other words, how to obtain a random ordering of a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, and the code is a bit too long for a comment, but do you mean something like the following?

```
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stackoverflow$ cat shuffle.f90
Program shuffle

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: n = 10

  Integer, Dimension( 1:n ) :: choices

  Real :: a

  Integer :: n_chosen
  Integer :: this
  Integer :: tmp
  Integer :: i

  choices = (/ ( i, i = 1, n ) /)

  n_chosen = 0
  Do i = 1, n
     Call random_number( a )
     this = a * ( n - n_chosen ) + 1
     Write( *, * ) 'Chosen ', choices( this )
     tmp = choices( this )
     choices( this ) = choices( n - n_chosen )
     choices( n - n_chosen ) = tmp
     n_chosen = n_chosen + 1
  End Do

End Program shuffle
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stackoverflow$ nagfor shuffle.f90
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3.1(907)
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination]
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stackoverflow$ ./a.out
 Chosen  5
 Chosen  10
 Chosen  4
 Chosen  9
 Chosen  8
 Chosen  2
 Chosen  6
 Chosen  3
 Chosen  1
 Chosen  7
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stackoverflow$ ./a.out
 Chosen  6
 Chosen  3
 Chosen  5
 Chosen  4
 Chosen  9
 Chosen  8
 Chosen  10
 Chosen  2
 Chosen  7
 Chosen  1
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stackoverflow$
```

Comment: The problem is I want to use the result as a label.
Here from your codes we have an array and I can not use this as a label.
I need just random integer between 1 and N.
Your code seems good but I have to modify this if i can.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and I used it in my program. it works but the problem is I did it in a **time interval** between 0 and t and every time it makes a same number order :D but the good point is without any repeats in each one.

```
  Program shuffle
  Implicit None
  Integer, Parameter :: num = 27
  Integer, Dimension( 1:num ) :: jj
  Real*8 uni,ir
  Integer :: n_chosen
  Integer :: this
  Integer :: tmp
  Integer :: i,ii
  jj = (/ ( i, i = 1, num ) /)
  ir=1245.d0
  n_chosen = 0
  Do i = 1, num
   Call ran(ir,uni)
   this = uni * ( num - n_chosen ) + 1
   ii=jj(this)
   tmp = jj( this )
   jj( this ) = jj( num - n_chosen )
   jj( num - n_chosen ) = tmp
   n_chosen = n_chosen + 1
  End Do
  end program
```